# scattered line is not metrizable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How to prove: scattered line is not metrizable?

I proved that it is not second countable, not separable. It is normal. Urysohn metrization theorem wont help as it is not separable. What property of metric space is it not satisfying?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Prove that $\Bbb Q$ is a closed set that is not a $G_\delta$-set: in a metric space every closed set **is** a $G_\delta$-set. You’ll want to use the Baire category theorem in $\Bbb R$. (For future reference, you may find it useful to know that this space is also called the *Michael line*.)

Answer (score 0):

To polish up the method Brian M. Scott introduced above,
$\Bbb Q$ is a closed subset of the scattered line because its complement Irr is obviously an open subset of the scattered line. Suppose scattered line can be completely metrizable. Then $\Bbb Q$ can be completely metrizable with the induced topology. Since the interior of $\Bbb Q$ with respect to the scattered line topology is empty, by the Baire Category Theorem this leads to a contradiction.